# May I omit from my tax return pages on which I've left all fields blank?

Tags: united-states, taxes

For example, when filing Form 1120 for 2018 by mail, if I've left all entry spaces on page 2 (Schedule C) blank, may I leave out page 2?

Comment: Why *would* you want to do this?

Comment: @ceejayoz Practically if nothing else it could cause the mailing to be cheaper if the OP is using a weight (or size) based service. It would also presumably save paper and ink...

Comment: @Vality The time spent doing this (and posting the question here) would be of more value than the penny or two saved annually.

Comment: @ceejayoz While you are probably correct in most cases, I have filed tax documents internationally via fedex air and it has often cost $60-100 for half a dozen sheets. Still, I think the question is reasonable and answerable even if not relevant to most folks.

Comment: @Vality If it's $60 for 6 sheets, I suspect it'll be $60 for one sheet.

Comment: Another approach is to print the forms double-sided. It doesn't save ink but it saves paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look at the instructions for [Form 1120](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1120.pdf) there is a section titled 'Assembling the Return'. I do not see any instructions saying any of the pages or schedules are optional.

This is a case of 'better safe than sorry'. I would not invite further scrutiny on my tax return just to save the marginal cost of printing and mailing one sheet of paper.

Answer (score 0):

A blank field in a mailed form is different than a page that wasn't sent. You could later argue that you did send the page with the fields filled out. The IRS will not accept a form with pages missing.

with that said I don't see how you can leave them blank. It seems like there should be a 0 in all of the fields.

Comment: Well, in the example I gave, I couldn't later argue that I did send page 2 with the entry spaces filled out (because I left lines 4 & 29b on page 1 blank). How do you know the IRS won't accept a form with pages missing? Well, I thought you could leave an entry space blank instead of entering 0.00.

Comment: "You could later argue" -- not if you include a note listing all pages that should be understood as blank -- though that doesn't mean the IRS won't question it. "I don't see how you can leave them blank" -- there are many cases where instructions call for blank rather than zero -- a form may have entire sections that don't apply. And what about a field computed by division?